# Number of entries per 2 groups in 2 columns

Tags: excel

new to excel and instead stuck with pivot tables.

I have the following requirement:

I have to count the (distinct) number of users per company per group of groups.

The **initial datatable** looks like the following (and many other columns):

```
COMPANIES|GROUPS  | USERS
...............................
|Company1 | Group1 | User1 |
|Company1 | Group1 | User2 |
|Company1 | Group2 | User3 |
|Company1 | Group3 | User4 |
|Company2 | Group2 | User2 |
|Company2 | Group1 | User1 |
|Company3 | Group3 | User5 |
|Company3 | Group3 | User5 | 
|Company3 | Group1 | User6 |
|Company3 | Group1 | User7 |
|Company3 | Group1 | User8 |
|Company3 | Group2 | User9 |
```

The **result** should be the following:

```
COMPANIES | Group1&2 | Group3
.....................................
 COMPANY1 | 3        | 1
 COMPANY2 | 2        | 0
 COMPANY3 | 4        | 1
```

What I've done is: I created a Pivot table, putted the group into the columns and the company into the rows. Then I selected f.e. group1&2 or group3 in the coulmns and generated in the value-area the distinct number.

I did that for any group of groups, so I have two tables with the correct results. But what I need is one table with the results of those two tables.

Where I'm stuck is the point that I have to group the groups. In this example here I have to group the group1 and group2 into one column.

So my question is:

Is there a way to "merge" the two pivot-tables? -> The companies must match and i just need the overall-value (not the value for each group). The tables can have a different amount of companys and groups..

OR

Is there a better way to solve my problem than pivot tables? And if so, which one?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it now with creating a new table which contains the data from the old table (just referencing the old data) with a new column which contains the groups of groups.

Did this with `IF(data="group1";"GROUP1&2"; IF(data="group2"; ......  ))`

With that new table it's possible now for me to create my pivot-table.

I don't think that's a good solution but at least it is a solution..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with a single Pivot table like this:

[image]

Which should result in this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @cybernetic.nomand for your answer. I actually forgot to tell you my big problem: I have to group the groups, so i wont have three colums for group1,2,3. I need to have 2 columns: Group1&2  and Group3. I updated my question so far